# Ros is permenantly installed after following the installation steps?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey, i wanted to ask when i follow the installation steps given on the site, i execute the commands" Ubuntu install of ROS Jade" and when i reach the end do i need to verify that ros is installed? When i close the terminal ROS vanishes? How can i know that whenever i open UBUNTU Ros will be installed?

Because when i go through the steps and verify by typing "ros versionros" it says"unversioned" and when i close and open terminal again it says"command ros not found" i know it maybe a silly question but i am a newbie:)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/228003/ros-is-permenantly-installed-after-following-the-installation-steps?/) by [Knowledge](https://answers.ros.org/users/26126/knowledge/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2016-03-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Once you've installed ROS via apt-get, it is permanently installed.

Note that the [environment setup](http://wiki.ros.org/jade/Installation/Ubuntu#jade.2BAC8-Installation.2BAC8-DebEnvironment.Environment_setup) instructions are critical. Commands like "roscore" won't be available unless you've properly "sourced" a setup.bash file. These setup.bash files automatically control a variety of [ROS environment variables](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/EnvironmentVariables), and some non-ROS environment variables as well. These environment variables are critical to ROS functionality. Every terminal you open has a different set of environment variables. Meaning, you'll need to "source" a setup.bash file in every terminal you want to use ROS in. The following commands from the installation instructions are actually modify your user's "~/.bashrc" file to force the primary ROS Jade setup.bash file to be "sourced" every time the "~/.bashrc" file is sourced.

```
echo "source /opt/ros/jade/setup.bash" >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
```

Finally note that the "~/.bashrc" file is automatically sourced every time you open a new terminal. Thus if you run the commands above, every terminal should be able to use ROS commands.

Don't worry about the `rosversion ros` returning `<unversioned>`. That command used to work, but now AFAIK, ROS versions are no longer numbered. Instead, you should use `rosversion -d` to see which version of ROS you are using.

---

Originally posted by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) with karma: 9031 on 2016-03-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Knowledge](https://answers.ros.org/users/26126/knowledge/) on 2016-03-02**:
thanks it says "jade" when i type "rosversion -d", this means now it is permanently installed?

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2016-03-03**:
yes                       .